# How to improve monitor contrast ratio?

Tags: display, colors, contrast

I bought a monitor recently, and altough it was quite cheap, it looked good enough at the store and most of the reviews said the image quality was good. When I got home and tried it I started having buyers remorse, the contrast ratio was so bad compared to the laptop I was connecting it to, even after lots of attempts to improve the quality, that I was literally unable to use it.

Today I gave it another go, but just as I was about to give up, I noticed that even though the contrast ratio was terrible on Windows itself, the monitor menu, which is black and white, had perfect contrast ratio! I was using this page, http://www.lagom.nl/lcd-test/contrast_ratio.php, to test my contrast ratio, and the blacks and whites of the monitor menu didn't even compare to these ones!

So, for the third time, I tried to fix my monitor, and this time I stroke gold (maybe silver or I wouldn't need this question)! I went to "Control Panel -> Hardware and Sound -> Display -> Calibrate color" and I actually managed to improve the quality quite a lot! Now, my monitor is finally usable, but still, if I go to the page I mentioned in the above paragraph, and compare it to the monitor menu, the contrast still seems much better in the menu!

So, the question is, is there any other way that I can try to improve my contrast ratio and actually get the blacks to be black?

P.S: My monitor is this one, in case it matters: http://www.currys.co.uk/gbuk/computing/monitors-and-projectors/pc-monitors/philips-227e4lhab-full-hd-21-5-led-monitor-21853516-pdt.html

Answer (score 0):

Turn down the brightness.  Factory default is usually way too bright.  This will improve your black level and contrast.

Your Philips 227E4LHAB also has a dynamic contrast feature they call "SmartImage Lite".  Check that it's enabled in your monitor's settings.

If you're still unhappy, return it, and look for MVA or PVA panel monitor next time.